# How to update aws auto-scaling group min & max configurations using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to come up with a solution for aws cost optimization. I am able to do it with cloudwatch rule and Lambda, this approach is working fine if I have to directly stop the instance and no auto-scaling group is associated with that instance.
Problem is when we are ,managing the instances using auto-scaling group. I am able to scale up the only instance associated with one auto-scaling group at one time using lambda. My use case is that I have to scale up multiple instances associated with multiple auto-scaling groups using lambda.

### There is one method which aws provide to update the autoscaling configuration as below:

```
var params = {
  AutoScalingGroupName: "my-auto-scaling-group", 
  MaxSize: 3, 
  MinSize: 1
 }
 autoscaling.updateAutoScalingGroup(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 })
```

---

But this way I can only update the configurations of 1 auto-scaling group at one time. Is there any way we can do it for multiple instances associated with multiple auto-scaling groups?

Answer (score 0):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const AUTOSCALING = new AWS.AutoScaling({region : "region-name"})

let asgarr = []    //array for autoscaling group names

const decreasecapacity = (everyparam) =>{
    var params = {
        AutoScalingGroupName: everyparam, 
        MaxSize: 0, 
        MinSize: 0
    };
       AUTOSCALING.updateAutoScalingGroup(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
}

asgarr.forEach(Element=>decreasecapacity(Element));
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.